# Norm Group of unramified extension of certain degree

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, local-field

I am going through Neukirch's algebraic number theory, when I stumbled upon this result, which is not too clear to me.

Here take $L| K$ to be a finite abelian extension of local fields, $\pi$ to be prime elements, $U^{(n)}$ the higher unit groups, and $N_{L|K}: L^{*} \mapsto K^{*}$ the norm map.

In particular, this is used in the proof of the local version of the Kronecker Weber Theorem. He argues that $(p^{f}) \times U_{\mathbb{Q}_{p}}^{(n)} \subseteq N_{L|K}(L^{*})$ for some carefully chosen $f$ and $n$. I guess more generally for a field extension $L|K$, we have $\pi_{K}^{f} \times U_{K}^{(n)} \subseteq N_{L|K}(L^{*}). $ I guess this follows since $N(L^{*})$ will contain some power of $\pi_{K}$ as $N(L^{*})$ is open of finite index, and $U_{K}^{(n)}$ form a basis of neighbourhoods of 1.  Moreover, $(\pi_{K})^f \subseteq N_{L|K}(L^{*})$, since it has finite index in $K^{*}$ by the isomorphism $\text{G}(L|K) \cong K^{*}/N_{L|K}L^{*}$, so we have $\pi_{K}^{(f)} \subseteq N_{L|K}(L^{*})$.

Overall, $\pi_{K}^{(f)} \times U_{K}^{(n)} \subseteq N_{L|K}(L^{*})$.

So far so good.

He then argues that $(p^{f}) \times U_{\mathbb{Q}_{p}}^{(n)} =\bigg((p)\times U_{\mathbb{Q}_{p}}^{(n)}\bigg) \cap \bigg((p^{f})\times U_{\mathbb{Q}_{p}}\bigg)$, and he claims that the the class field corresponding to $((p^{f})\times U_{\mathbb{Q}_{p}}) $ is the unramified extension of degree $f$. I guess more generally the unramified extension of degree $n$ will have norm group equal to $(\pi_{K}^{f})\times U_{K}$, but this step is not really clear to me.

Any hints or explanations are welcome.

Comment: I managed to solve this after all. I might add the solution in the comments.

Comment: Hi, I'm stuck at the same spot. Did you figure out with the unramified extension of degree $n$ has norm group $(\pi_K^n) \times U_K$?

Comment: You can use Proposition 5.7 from chapter IV which gives the reciprocity law for unramified extensions, and proposition 6.2 to show that any unit is a norm for unramified extensions.

Comment: Oh! I see, thank you so much. I got confused because of $U_K$ and ${U_K}^{(1)}$!